# Finding a specific node using Xpath and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, xpath, html-agility-pack

Using HtmlAgilityPack and Linq and the following html string I am trying to get the  "Last Date to file:" date. The XPath has eluded me

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><b></b> John E. Clement
   </td>
<td>
<b></b>
</td>
<td>
<b>Chapter: </b>1
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<b>Office:/b>Littleton 
</td>
<td>
<b>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; </b>
</td>
<td><b>Last Date to file: </b>**04/18/2017**</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Boss: </b>Michael Meyer </td>
<td><b></b></td>
<td><b>Last Date to file again: </b>06/06/2018</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My c# code is:

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("*My file with the html above*");
var lastDate = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(a=>a.InnerText.Contains("Last");
```

It seems that there should be a way to get a single node based on the innertext but I am getting a collection of all the **td** tags in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DocumentNode.Descendants()` effectively gets all nodes in the document except the root. 
The `InnerText` property of a node includes all text contained inside that node, including descendant nodes. For example, given the html

```
<div>
    This <span>is some <b>text</b></span>
</div>
```

the `InnerText` of the `div` tag is "This is some text".

Therefore, the query `doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(a=>a.InnerText.Contains("Last");` will return the `b` tag that contains "Last", as well as the `td` tag that contains the `b`, as well as the `tr` that contains the `td`, as well as the `table` that contains the `tr` and so on.

Try filtering by node type, as well as InnerText, like so:
`var lastDate = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(a => a.Name == "td" && a.InnerText.Contains("Last"));`

This returns only 2 td elements.